# Issues after updating android studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea

THE FOLLOWING IS THE ERROR

> Cannot load project:
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException:
>   com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException:
>   com/jediterm/terminal/ui/TerminalWidget [Plugin:
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal]

Comment: I am not able to create a new project and open the existing ones.

Comment: So disable the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Because your plugin is not available in the latest version, you can uninstall the plugin in the settings to restart